# How to create a table with group hierarchy in an Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse

I would like to create a table view in my Eclipse plug-in that has grouped / tree-like hierarchy... just like the table you see in Eclipse for the "Expressions" view where there is a + or a triangle that you can click to expand the table entries.

What class do I need to use to generate this table and are there any good examples online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically called a Tree-Table.

Here is a short [example for SWT implementation](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/CreateaTreeTable.htm) that creates something like that.

Hope that helps.